# Ten commandments contradiction

Tags: old-testament

Does the new testament override, or replace the commandment of honor your mother and father, and thy shall not murder?

Comment: Mark 12:30-31 (New International Version): Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’ The second is this: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no commandment greater than these.”

Comment: Jesus made the commandment. Guess what? He's also citing the Christian Old Testament.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site. Don't take the previous comments as discouragement. It can be tough for new visitors to "get" what this site is about. (It's not what you'd think.) As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify this question. Is there some verse in the NT that you see as commanding Christians to curse their parents and murder people? That seems a little far out.

Comment: Please change your question to something along the lines of "There is a tendency in Christianity to assume that the the Law of the Old Testament is irrelevant for Christians. Does this extend to the 10 Commandments? In particular, honoring thy mother and father, or though shalt not murder?"

Answer (score 5):

No, but Jesus reaffirms these. In **Matthew 19:16-19,** He tells the rich young ruler,

> And behold, a man came up to him, saying, “Teacher, what good deed
>   must I do to have eternal life?”
>
> And he said to him, “Why do you ask me about what is good? There is
>   only one who is good. If you would enter life, keep the commandments.”
>
> He said to him, “Which ones?” And Jesus said, *“You shall not murder,*
>   You shall not commit adultery, You shall not steal, You shall not bear
>   false witness,
>
> *Honor your father and mother,* and, You shall love your neighbor as
>   yourself.”

Answer (score 4):

Mark 12:30-31 (New International Version):

> Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and
>   with all your mind and with all your strength.’ The second is this:
>   ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no commandment greater than
>   these.”

It looks like Jesus is just restating the Christian Old Testament.

Comment: I can say with 100% certainty that Jesus was not restating the Christian Old Testament

Answer (score 1):

Verses others have mentioned. Also:

Matthew 15:3-7 He answered and said to them, “Why do you also transgress the commandment of God because of your tradition? For God commanded, saying, ‘Honor your father and your mother’; and, ‘He who curses father or mother, let him be put to death.’ But you say, ‘Whoever says to his father or mother, “Whatever profit you might have received from me is a gift to God”—  6 then he need not honor his father or mother.’ Thus you have made the commandment of God of no effect by your tradition"

Maybe possibly you are thinking of: Matthew 10:34 "He who loves father or mother more than Me is not worthy of Me." In context, though, Jesus is saying that members of your own family may try to stand between you and God, and if that happens, God must come first. I have never understood the command to honor my parents to mean that I should put them before God. If my parents said, "We want you to help us rob and kill someone", I would not think that God would want me to help them do that based on the command to honor one's parents.

Answer (score 0):

Ephesians 6:1-3
King James Version (KJV)

6 Children, obey your parents in the Lord: for this is right.

2 Honour thy father and mother; which is the first commandment with promise;

3 That it may be well with thee, and thou mayest live long on the earth.

These verses tells us that we should honor our father and mother.

Matthew 5:20-26
King James Version (KJV)

20 For I say unto you, That except your righteousness shall exceed the righteousness of the scribes and Pharisees, ye shall in no case enter into the kingdom of heaven.

21 Ye have heard that it was said of them of old time, Thou shalt not kill; and whosoever shall kill shall be in danger of the judgment:

22 But I say unto you, That whosoever is angry with his brother without a cause shall be in danger of the judgment: and whosoever shall say to his brother, Raca, shall be in danger of the council: but whosoever shall say, Thou fool, shall be in danger of hell fire.

23 Therefore if thou bring thy gift to the altar, and there rememberest that thy brother hath ought against thee;

24 Leave there thy gift before the altar, and go thy way; first be reconciled to thy brother, and then come and offer thy gift.

25 Agree with thine adversary quickly, whiles thou art in the way with him; lest at any time the adversary deliver thee to the judge, and the judge deliver thee to the officer, and thou be cast into prison.

26 Verily I say unto thee, Thou shalt by no means come out thence, till thou hast paid the uttermost farthing.

These verse expand the meaning of murder to include hatred. Because God cares what is in the heart of a person.